# How to call next value in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

i used the dict

```
LEVEL_XP = {
   0: 0,
   1: 5,
   2: 13,
   3: 20
}
```

and the code

```py
new_level = int(level)
for level_on, xp_needed in LEVEL_XP.items():
    i = LEVEL_XP[xp_needed]

    if 0 <= i:
       if xp != i:
          print('nothing')
          break
       else:
          new_level = int(level_on) + 1
          print('level up')
          break

    else:
       new_level = int(level)
       break
```

where i could call `level` and `xp` from database and it works fine.
the problem is after i reach `13` xp, i dont level up to `2` and its printing `nothing`.
i've found the reason that the `xp_needed` calls only `0` which is the first value in the dict.
How can i get the code consider next value which is `13` in the dict when i am level `1`?
and How to do if i like erase the whole xp to 0 and restart it with level `1`, so the code need to call `13` as `xp_needed` next, not `5`?

Comment: Your code seems to depend on something called `LEVELS_AND_XP` which is not present in your question. Please make sure you provide a complete example of you problem, otherwise it's *really* hard to help without guessing.

Comment: oh sorry,, was my bad.. editted it :) and thanks for poppin it out

Comment: `i = LEVEL_XP[xp_needed]` is useless and should techincally throw keyerror

Comment: i've had the normal way like with only `xp_needed` but as to enumerate i've taken the dict calling way and still both giving me the same response

Comment: If there are only 4 levels you don't even need a dictionary. if else is complety fine

Comment: nop..there are like tons of levels and i've only included 4 levels cuz i cant add all of the dict in here

Comment: use list and enumerate. the index will be level and value will be `xp`. While iterating if `current_xp >= xp` then the index will be level and you can just `break` from iteration

Comment: the best part about list is that you can use methods like linspace or arange and don't have to write the whole LEVEL_XP list manually.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Is `LEVEL_XP` the amount of xp *to* the level, or the amount once you got there? And is that the total amount of xp, or is it reset every time meaning it's the xp for each individual level?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the code consider next value ... ?

Use the `while` loop below.
It takes advantage of experience being monotonic with level.
We can probe each `[level + 1]` element quite efficiently,
without having to visit the "tons" of levels you mentioned.
We only examine levels that could be relevant.

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, level=0, xp=0):
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Character: level {self.level}, xp {self.xp}>'

    def adjust_to_increased_experience(self, new_xp):
        assert new_xp >= self.xp
        assert new_xp >= LEVEL_XP[self.level]
        while LEVEL_XP.get(self.level + 1, math.inf) <= new_xp:
            self.level += 1
        self.xp = new_xp
```